# Sending PySpark results to MQTT broker with foreachRDD and paho

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to send a DStream with my computed results to an MQTT broker, but foreachRDD keeps crashing.

I'm running Spark 2.4.3 with Bahir for MQTT subscribe compiled from git master. Everything works up to this point. Before trying to publish my results with MQTT, I tried to saveAsFiles(), and that worked (but isn't exactly what I want).

```py
def sendPartition(part):
    # code for publishing with MQTT here
    return 0


mydstream = MQTTUtils.createStream(ssc, brokerUrl, topic)
mydstream = packets.map(change_format) \
    .map(lambda mac: (mac, 1)) \
    .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + b)
mydstream.foreachRDD(lambda rdd: rdd.foreachPartition(sendPartition)) # line 56
```

the resulting Error I get is this:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: An exception was raised by Python:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/SPARK_HOME/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/streaming/util.py", line 68, in call
    r = self.func(t, *rdds)
  File "/SPARK_HOME/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/streaming/dstream.py", line 161, in <lambda>
    func = lambda t, rdd: old_func(rdd)
  File "/path/to/my/code.py", line 56, in <lambda>
    mydstream.foreachRDD(lambda rdd: rdd.foreachPartition(sendPartition))
  File "/SPARK_HOME/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 806, in foreachPartition
    self.mapPartitions(func).count()  # Force evaluation
  File "/SPARK_HOME/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1055, in count
    return self.mapPartitions(lambda i: [sum(1 for _ in i)]).sum()
  File "/SPARK_HOME/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1046, in sum
    return self.mapPartitions(lambda x: [sum(x)]).fold(0, operator.add)
  File "/SPARK_HOME/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 917, in fold
    vals = self.mapPartitions(func).collect()
  File "/SPARK_HOME/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 816, in collect
    sock_info = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
  File "/SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 55
```

with lots of java errors following, but I suspect the error is in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you able to run other Spark commands?  At the end of your stack trace, you see `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 55`.  This indicates that you are running Spark on an unsupported version of Java.

Spark is not yet compatible with Java 11 (due to limitations imposed by Scala I think).  Try configuring spark to use Java 8.  The specifics vary a bit based on what platform you're on.  You'll probably need to install Java 8, and change the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to point towards the new installation.

Comment: thank you. I just changed the Java version for some other software requiring java 11 and forgot to change it back. It works now (with Java 8)